# Mostrar uma dialog com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5, dialog

Eu tenho a seguinte html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <dialog id="my-dialog"></dialog>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#my-dialog').showModal();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eu consigo abrir a dialog com o seguinte javascript:

```
document.getElementById("my-dialog").showModal();
```

Mas não encontrei uma forma de abrir o modal utilizando o jQuery, eu já tentei isso:

```
$('#my-dialog').showModal();
```

Mas me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).showModal is not a function
```

Existe uma forma de abrir uma dialog utilizando o jQuery?

Comment: Parece que não colocou a biblioteca do JQuey antes do código, coloque essa e teste: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Eu já tenho importado a biblioteca do jQuery antes do meu código javascript. Eu até utilizo algumas funções sem nenhum problema da biblioteca antes de eu tentar abrir a dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Toda chamada do jQuery retorna uma **coleção** de objetos, mesmo se a busca for por ID que deve retornar sempre 1 elemento, ele vai retornar uma coleção de 1 elemento jQuery.

Seu primeiro exemplo (`document.getElementById("my-dialog").showModal();`), você faz uma busca no DOM com JavaScript, que retorna 1 elemento JavaScript e chama o método `showModal`.

Seu segundo exemplo (`$('#my-dialog').showModal();`), você faz uma busca no DOM com o jQuery, que retorna uma coleção de elementos jQuery e tenta fazer a chamada do método `showModal` nesta coleção de elementos jQuery, porém, neste caso este método não existe nos objetos jQuery, retornando assim o erro.

Duas possíveis soluções a princípio:

### Primeira possível solução

Acessar o primeiro elemento JavaScript que está "dentro" da coleção jQuery, já que sua busca é por ID e deve retornar sempre 1 elemento. Você consegue fazer isso como se fosse um Array mesmo:

```
$('#my-dialog')[0].showModal();
```

Neste caso, se seu seletor não retornar elementos (o ID não existir no DOM por ex.) esse código vai retornar erro, pois a posição "0" não vai existir, já que a coleção estará vazia. Este caso pode ser tratado por algo assim:

```
if($('#my-dialog').length > 0) {
    $('#my-dialog')[0].showModal();
}
```

### Segunda possível solução

Criar este "método" no jQuery.

Conforme a [documentação](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/):

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.showModal = function() {
      this[0].showModal();
      return this;
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```

E você poderá fazer:

```
$('#my-dialog').showModal();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado isso resolveu o meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Via *javascript* você pode tentar `$('#my-dialog').modal('show');`.

Olha [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13183713/4551469) se precisar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas continuo com o mesmo erro

Comment: @DiegoHeusser você pode tirar um print e mostrar para a gente o erro?